# Multiple SP4T switches in single package?

Tags: analog-switch, spdt, displayport

I am trying to make my own KVM switch with DisplayPort connectors.

I have 4 inputs + 1 output (bidirectional), so I need a SP4T switch (I have chosen the [Infineon Technologies BGSA14GN10](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BGSA14GN10-DataSheet-v03_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46255dd933d0155e9e3e86f09ff) (which is an RF switcher but would still work)).

The problem:
Because DisplayPort has 20-pins, it would be inefficient to use 20 SP4T switches, so I am looking for another way to connect the 20-pin DP.
In my research, I found the Diodes Inc. PI3WVR13612ZLEX DisplayPort switcher, but I would rather not make the switching system from a hyper-specific part, so in the future, it is upgradeable and generalizable (I might want to use the same part for USB too). Also, the PI3WVR13612ZLEX only supports 2 channels.

My monitor would be running 1080p 240 FPS (but preferably 1440p 240FPS if possible) with HDR, and DisplayPort version is 1.4.

Does a part exists that has over 5 SP4T switches embedded in it (to save space)?

Or

What would another method be to do this?

Comment: I think dual 4:1 is as far as it goes for common parts.

Comment: There are 1:2 DisplayPort switches from many manufacturers. Build a 1:4 switch from three 1:2 switches.

Comment: Are you just looking for a 5P4T switch (or, theoretically, even a 20P4T switch)?

Comment: Kind of. I am looking for a 20p80t switch, or something similar.

Comment: Are you talking about an electromechanical switch? Because it's going to be difficult to get such high-speed signals through such a switch. Those RF switches probably are your best bet. And, switches with extremely high throw counts like your 80T switch are unlikely to exist--why do you need an 80T switch when you're talking about a 4T switch up to that point?

Comment: You also don't need 20 poles. There's no harm in leaving the grounds connected to the inactive connectors (unless you're doing something weird, in which case let us know what), so that's six (including the power return) pins on the connector that you don't need to switch. Additionally, pins 13, 14, 18, and 20 are all low-speed signals and power that can be switched with ordinary relays. That leaves only ten pins (two for each of the four lanes and one auxiliary channel) that need to be switched with something fancy.

Comment: Those same ten pins are also, to the extent of my knowledge, the only ones that carry high-speed signals in HDMI mode, too, so such a switch would equally support HDMI mode.

Comment: @Hearth: From my understanding of your previous comments, I just need to connect 10 pins using sp4t because the others can be left unconnected, or can be left to regular relays. So then, with the 10 pins I am using for high speed, how would I have 10 sp4t switches in a small area, while still maintaining enough space for the USB switch?